# Kernel source for Ubuntu 14.04 on Raspberry Pi 2?

Tags: 14.04, kernel, raspberrypi

**Anyone know where I can find the source of the Linux kernel  3.18.0-25-rpi2?**

This is the kernel from Ubuntu 14.04 image for Raspberry Pi 2:

> The kernel used by the Raspberry Pi 2 port is an Ubuntu-style kernel package of an "rpi2" flavor, e.g. linux-image-3.18.0-20-rpi2. Currently it is comprised of the following functionality:
>
> - Mainline 3.18.x
> - Fork of Ubuntu-3.18.0-14.15 from the ubuntu-vivid git tree
>
>   - Provides extra functionality such as aufs
>   - Also includes additional stability fixes, many of which have been rolled into mainline post-3.18.7
> - Raspberry Pi-specific patches from the rpi-3.18.y branch of Raspberry Pi's linux git tree

[Source](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi#Kernel)

I ran `apt-get source -b linux-image-$(uname -r)` which did build the kernel but it was 3.13.0-79.  I don't really understand why that happened. `flash-kernel` refused to install it as it is older than the existing 3.18 kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to compile Linux kernel 3.18.0-29-rpi2 with fbtft modules for Ubuntu 14.04 on Raspberry Pi 2.

This GitHub Gist contains the steps I followed:

https://gist.github.com/pdp7/440f522ff7060ab9ae72﻿

Linux kernel .deb package with fbtft modules:

**linux-image-3.18.0-29-rpi2_3.18.0-29.30_armhf.deb**

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_NI2VDamOOfakYwV3NESF81TWM

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link could help you out since it is specific to rpi.

Edit: I would have made this a comment but my rep is new and not able to yet.

[Fork of Ubuntu-3.18.0-14.15 from the ubuntu-vivid git tree](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-vivid.git/log/?qt=range&q=f8e80fa0d166ec8df70d769d0e679fed5d93add1)

Instructions for rpi and the source for the previous link are here.

Scroll close to the bottom for 14.04 bits.

[ARM/RaspberryPi](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi)

Comment: This should be a comment , you can improve your answer by editing it and adding important information from the link.